# Android emulator not working correctly

Tags: android, error-handling, android-emulator

after formatting my laptop I installed  Android sdk and I work with that properly and the emulator is worked. but after installed the Visual studio 2013, now when I'm going to run the emulator it gives a error message

**emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!**

What is that error ?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)? It's much better than the built in emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install HAXM from your SDK Manager. But we recommend Genymotion. Its perfect for android app testing